# Copy constructor in templated derived class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

Hopefully this will be an easy one.  In working on a solution for a different problem, I ran into the following problem:

```
template <class Base>
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  Derived() {};
  Derived(const Derived& rhs) :
    Base::Base(rhs) { };
};

struct X { };

void test()
{
  Derived<X> d1;
  Derived<X> d2(d1);
}


test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Derived<Base>::Derived(const   Derived<Base>&) [with Base = X]’:
test.cpp:34:19:   required from here
test.cpp:26:19: error: no type named ‘Base’ in ‘struct X’
         Base::Base(rhs) { };
                   ^
```

So, how does one write a copy constructor for a derived template class? (in the above example, assume that I have no ability to alter X and that its contents are nontrivial and subject to change)

Comment: It should be `Base(rhs)`, not `Base::Base(rhs)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call the constructor of the `Base` part of `Derived` all you need is

```
Derived(const Derived& rhs) :
    Base(rhs) { };
```

`Base::Base` tries to initialize a member of the type `Base` named `Base`.

Comment: That solves that.  :)  Have to wait six minutes to choose the answer though.

Comment: @KarenRei No problem.  Glad to help.

Comment: Note that `Base::Base` denotes the constructor(s) of `Base`. The key is that when writing down a constructor initializer list, you write the types, not the constructors.